# Extract coefficients from sum

Tags: probability-or-statistics, summation

I would like to extract coefficients of indexed variables from a large sum. The following is an example motivated by linear regression to illustrate the problem.

Consider the (unnormalised) log likelihood of a linear regression problem with design matrix `X`, observations `y`, and regression parameters `w` given by

```
logLikelihood = -gamma / 2 * Sum[(y[i] - Sum[X[i, j] w[j], {j, 1, p}]) ^ 2, {i, 1, n}]
```

I would like to use Mathematica to extract coefficients of indexed variables from the log-likelihood. For example, I would like to apply

```
SomeFunction[logLikelihood, w[k]^2]
```

and get the following result

```
- gamma / 2 * Sum[X[i,k] ^ 2, {i, 1, n}]
```

I have tried `Coefficient` and differentiating with respect to the variable of interest but both are not quite working as I would like.

Comment: Are `n` and `p` left as a variables, or do you plug in numbers for them?

Comment: I would like to leave `n` and `p` as variables.

Comment: You might want to look at http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65471/how-to-do-algebra-on-summations-of-variable-expressions.