# Expanding Log[Product[...]]

Tags: probability-or-statistics, expression-manipulation, products

I'm trying to get the log-likelihood of a Gaussian in the form

$$
p(\textbf{x}|u,\sigma^2)=\prod_{n=1}^{N}\mathcal{N}(x_n|\mu,\sigma^2) \quad (1)
$$

$$
\ln\ p(\textbf{x}|\mu,\sigma^2)=-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\sum_{n=1}^N{(x_n-\mu)^2}-\frac{N}{2}\ln\ \sigma^2-\frac{N}{2}\ln\ (2\pi) \quad (2)
$$

I've have

```
Log[Product[PDF[NormalDistribution[μ, σ], Subscript[x, n]], {n, 1, bigN}]]
```

which outputs

$$
\ln(\prod_{n=1}^{bigN}\frac{\mathrm e^{\frac{(-\mu+x_n)^2}{2\sigma^2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}).
$$

I tried `Expand`, `ExpandAll`, `PowerExpand`, but I can't seem to get it to display like in Equation (2 RHS).

From

```
Product[Log[PDF[NormalDistribution[μ, σ], Subscript[x, n]]], {n, 1, bigN}] // PowerExpand`
```

I get closer with

$$
\prod_{n=1}^{bigN}\left[\frac{1}{2}(-\ln 2-\ln\pi)-\ln\sigma-\frac{(-\mu+x_n)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right]
$$

Comment: Looks like there's a typo in your first line of code -- `x_n` should be `Subscript[x, n]`.  Though be careful, because using subscripts as variables can get you into trouble.

Comment: related https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/65991/1089

Answer (score 2):

```
logProd = Log[Product[PDF[NormalDistribution[μ, σ], Subscript[x, n]], {n, 1, bigN}]];

$Assumptions = {σ > 0};
product /: Log[product[a_, b_]] := Sum[FunctionExpand @ Log @ a, b]

Block[{Product = product}, logProd]
```

[image]

```
% // TeXForm
```

> $\sum _{n=1}^{\text{bigN}} \left(\log \left(e^{-\frac{\left(x_n-\mu \right){}^2}{2 \sigma
>    ^2}}\right)-\log (\sigma )-\frac{1}{2} \log (2 \pi )\right)$

Answer (score 0):

How about starting with a replacement rule?

```
logProduct /. Log[Product[expr_, spec_]] :> Sum[Log[expr], spec]
```

> [image: output]

Comment: Since `spec` can be more than one argument, the matching pattern should probably be `spec__` (with 2 blanks).